# handlebars partial inside of a partial

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp, handlebars.js

I'm building out a site where I want to have a layout wrapper for most pages (but not all). What I'm trying to do is use a partial for the layout wrapper and then pass other content partials into this master layout.

Contents of `layout.hbs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {{> head }}
    <body>
        {{> nav}}
        {{ content }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in `somefile.hbs`

```
{{> layout myPartial.hbs}}
```

I'm rending my handlebars templates with gulp.

I can get this working if I pass markup directly into `layout.hbs` but what I'd like to do is pass the contents of another partial file into the layout wrapper.

```
{{> layout content="<div>foo</div>"}} // Renders ok
```

Is there another way I should be approaching a global layout wrapper?

Comment: I've always preferred pugjs to handlebars because of its [template inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) structure. It looks like there are some [add-ons](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/handlebars-layouts) available to add that functionality.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working with [dynamic partial lookup syntax](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#dynamic-partials).

### Working solution

Contents of `layout.hbs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {{> head }}
    <body>
        {{> nav}}
        {{> (lookup . 'partial') }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Contents of `someFile.hbs`

```
// Allows me to hit http://w.x.y.z/someDir/someFile
{{> layout partial='someDir/_someFile'}}
```

Contents of `someDir/_someFile.hbs`

```
// Content injected into the layout and can include nested layouts
<h1>Some content I want to render</h1>
```